# Render comments form in any page

Tags: forms, drupal-7, comments

I want to know how to render a comments form of a specific node in any page (ex. user profile). I've trying with drupal_get_form but it shows an error.

```
drupal_get_form('mytype_node_form', array('nid' => $nid));
```

Solutions & clues are welcome :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should use the proper ID of the comment form: `'comment_form'` instead of `'mytype_node_form'`.

The code

```php
drupal_get_form('comment_form', array('nid' => $nid));
```

used to work for me in Drupal 6. In Drupal 7, function [comment_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_form/7) is expecting an object parameter instead of array. This code should work for you:

```php
$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->nid = $nid;
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment);
```